# Polynomial irreducibiliy with substitution (need evaluation of logic)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification

One thing I have seen several times when trying to show that a polynomial $p(x)$ is irreducible over a field $F$ is that instead of showing that $p(x)$ is irreducible, I am supposed to show that $p(ax + b)$ is irreducible $a,b\in F $. This is supposedly equivalent. That does make sense, and I have a logical explanation for it. However,  many times I've seen that my logic is wrong. So, I need my explanation evaluated.

Proposition: $p(x)$ is irreducible iff $p(x+b)$ is irreducible.

In the algebraic closure of F, $p(x)$ can be written as product of linear factors:

$p(x) = \prod_{i \in I} (x-x_i) \textrm{ where } x_i \in F' \textrm{ for all }i$

That means $p(x+b) = \prod_{i \in I} (x+b-x_i)$

So, the roots of $p(x+b)$ are $-b+x_i$ for $i \in I$, and since $b$ is in the field, these are in the field if $x_i$ are in the field. Since $b$ can be negative, this proof works both ways.

If $p(x)$ is irreducible, one of the linear factors will have an $x_i$ that is not in the field. Therefore, $x_i-b$ will not be in the field either. Thus, $p(x+b)$ is irreducible if $p(x)$ is irreducible.

Proposition: $p(x)$ is irreducible iff $p(ax)$ is irreducible.

$p(x) = \prod_{i = 0}^n (x-x_i)$

That means $p(ax) = \prod_{i = 0}^n (ax-x_i) = a^{n+1}\prod_{i = 0}^n \left(x-\dfrac{x_i}{a}\right)$. So, the roots of $p(ax)$ are $\dfrac{x_i}{a}$ for $i \in I$. If one of these $x_i$'s is not in the field, neither is $\dfrac{x_i}{a}$. Again, this proof works both ways since fields contain multiplicative inverses.

The idea that $p(x)$ is only irreducible if $p(ax + b)$ is irreducible is a consequence of these two propositions.

Comment: Alternatively if $a\neq 0$, then the map $$p(x) \mapsto p(ax+b)$$ is an isomorphism of $F[x]$ into itself.

Comment: I am still a little weak on isomorphisms. So, I know you are telling me that there is a homomorphism that is in one-to-one correspondence from F[x] to itself. However, I am not sure how. More importantly, how does it answer my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all polynomials reducible over a field $F$ can be written as a product of linear factors. For example, the factorization of $x^3 - 1$ over $\Bbb Q$ into irreducible polynomials is
$$x^3 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1),$$
in particular, into a product of a linear factor and a quadratic one.

Your proof doesn't require a factorization into linear factors, though, just a (nontrivial) factorization, so it is easy to modify to produce a valid proof.

Comment: Yes, but, I have seen the algebraic closure of some field F used to show that some polynomial in F[x] does not have a solution in F. That is the same as I have done above; Essentially, solving the polynomial in the algebraic closure, and showing that those solutions are not in the field F. Why is this not valid?